# Reading image1d in fragment shader problem

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

i'm trying to read the corresponding color for each cell of the voronoi diagram in a fragment shader from an sampler1D and the result is this:

[image: Voronoi Diagram]

Then i'm creating a lookat and perspective matrix and moving the camera in z and x axis using the keyboard, and if i move on the x axis each cell still have its corresponding color, but when i move on the z axis it seems like it loses the indices for the color buffer that i created:

Voronoi Diagram before moving along z axis
[image: Voronoi Diagram with camera, before moving on the z axis]

Voronoi Diagram after moving along z axis
[image: Voronoi Diagram with camera, after moving on the z axis]

so to check if i'm losing the indices in the fragment shader after moving on the z axis with the camera, i tried to debug my fragment shader using the index of each point (generated randomly on the client side) as the color for each cell, like this (i'm generating 5 points):

Voronoi Diagram with camera, before moving on the z axis using the index as the color
[image: Voronoi Diagram with camera, before moving on the z axis using the index as the color]

and

Voronoi Diagram with camera, after moving on the z axis using the index as the color
[image: Voronoi Diagram with camera, after moving on the z axis using the index as the color]

and it works it doesn't lose the index of each cell, but i want to be able to read the color from the texture that i created.

here is my client code:

```
class VoronoiJFA
    : public Core
{
public:
    VoronoiJFA()
        : Core(512, 512, "VoronoiJFA"), size_space(512)
    {}

    virtual void Start() override
    {
        srand(time(nullptr));

        shader_points = new Shader("draw_points.vert", "draw_points.frag");
        shader_voronoi_jfa = new Shader("voronoi_jfa.vert", "voronoi_jfa.frag");
        shader_display_voronoi = new Shader("display_voronoi.vert", "display_voronoi.frag");

        size_points = 5;
        size_triangles = 16000;

        eye = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
        target = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
        up = vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        vec4* p = new vec4[size_points];
        vec4* c = new vec4[size_points];
        // Generating  random point for voronoi diagram
        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < size_points; i++)
        {
            float x{ (float(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 2.0f - 1.0f) };
            float y{ (float(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 2.0f - 1.0f) };
            //the "i" variable is used to store the index of each point to reference the color in the display_voronoi.frag shader
            p[i] = vec4(x, y, 0.0f, i);

            float r{ float(rand()) / RAND_MAX };
            float g{ float(rand()) / RAND_MAX };
            float b{ float(rand()) / RAND_MAX };
            c[i] = vec4(r, g, b, 1.0f);
        }

        // The space_texture is where i'm gonna paint voronoi using offscreen rendering for voronoi JFA
        glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &space_texture);
        glTextureStorage2D(space_texture, 1, GL_RGBA32F, size_space, size_space);
        glBindImageTexture(0, space_texture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);

        // Here i store the colors for each voronoi cell
        glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 1, &colors_texture);
        glTextureStorage1D(colors_texture, 1, GL_RGBA32F, size_points);
        glTextureSubImage1D(colors_texture, 0, 0, size_points, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, c);
        glBindTextureUnit(2, colors_texture);


        // This is the fbo for the offscreen rendering to draw generate voronoi
        glCreateFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer_object);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer_object);
        glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, space_texture, 0);
        glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

        glCreateBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer_points);
        glNamedBufferStorage(vertex_buffer_points, sizeof(vec4) * size_points, p, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
        glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_points);
        glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_points);
        glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vertex_array_points, 0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
        glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vertex_array_points, 0);
        glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vertex_array_points, 0, 0);
        glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vertex_array_points, 0, vertex_buffer_points, 0, sizeof(vec4));

        Window::current->setColor(vec4(-1000000000.0f));
        delete[] p;
        delete[] c;
    }

    virtual void Update() override
    {
        static float time{ 0.0f };
        time += Time::deltaTime;

        if (Input::getKeyDown(KeyCode::Escape))
            Window::current->shouldClose(true);

        // Camera controls
        if (Input::getKey(KeyCode::A))
            eye = eye - normalize(cross(target, up)) * Time::deltaTime * 1.0f;
        if (Input::getKey(KeyCode::D))
            eye = eye + normalize(cross(target, up)) * Time::deltaTime * 1.0f;
        if (Input::getKey(KeyCode::S))
            eye = eye - target * Time::deltaTime * 1.0f;
        if (Input::getKey(KeyCode::W))
            eye = eye + target * Time::deltaTime * 1.0f;

        mat4 M;
        mat4 V;
        V = mat4::lookAt(eye, eye + target, up); // Virtual camera
        mat4 P;
        P = mat4::perspective(radians(45.0f), float(Window::current->getWidth()) / Window::current->getHeight(), 0.1f, 100.0f); // projection matrix

        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer_object);
        vec4 distance(-1000000000.0f);
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, &distance[0]);
        glViewport(0, 0, size_space, size_space);
        glMemoryBarrier(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BARRIER_BIT | GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT | GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT | GL_TEXTURE_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT | GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BARRIER_BIT);
        shader_points->use(); // Here i just paint the points generated previously in a texture 2D
        glUniform1f(0, time);
        vec2 mouse = (vec2(Input::mousePosition.x, Input::mousePosition.y) / vec2(Window::current->getWidth(), Window::current->getHeight())) * 2.0f - 1.0f;
        glUniform2fv(1, 1, &mouse[0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(2, 1, GL_FALSE, &M[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(3, 1, GL_FALSE, &V[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(4, 1, GL_FALSE, &P[0][0]);
        glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_points);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, size_points);
        glMemoryBarrier(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BARRIER_BIT | GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT | GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT | GL_TEXTURE_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT | GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BARRIER_BIT);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glViewport(0, 0, size_space, size_space);
        int step{ size_space / 2 };
        while(step >= 1)
        {
            shader_voronoi_jfa->use(); // Here i compute the voronoi diagram using JFA
            glUniform1i(2, step);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
            glMemoryBarrier(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BARRIER_BIT | GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT | GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT | GL_TEXTURE_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT | GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BARRIER_BIT);
            step /= 2;
        }
        step =  size_space / 2 ;
        while(step >= 1)
        {
            shader_voronoi_jfa->use(); // Again using JFA to eliminate "islands"
            glUniform1i(2, step);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
            glMemoryBarrier(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BARRIER_BIT | GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT | GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT | GL_TEXTURE_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT | GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BARRIER_BIT);
            step /= 2;
        }

        glViewport(0, 0, Window::current->getWidth(), Window::current->getHeight());
        shader_display_voronoi->use(); // Display voronoi diagram
        glUniform1i(0, size_space);
        glUniform1i(1, size_points);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    virtual void End() override
    {
        delete shader_points;
        delete shader_voronoi_jfa;

        glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer_points);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_points);

        glDeleteTextures(1, &space_texture);
        glDeleteTextures(1, &colors_texture);


        glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer_object);
    }

private:
    Shader* shader_points;
    Shader* shader_voronoi_jfa;
    Shader* shader_display_voronoi;

    GLuint vertex_buffer_points;
    GLuint vertex_array_points;

    GLuint space_texture;
    GLuint colors_texture;

    GLuint framebuffer_object;

    int size_space;
    int size_points;
    int size_triangles;

    vec3 eye;
    vec3 target;
    vec3 up;
};

#if 1
CORE_MAIN(VoronoiJFA)
#endif
```

my shaders are these:

draw_points.vert

```
#version 450 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 a_points;

layout(binding = 1, rgba32f) uniform image1D image_points;

layout(location = 0) uniform float u_time;
layout(location = 1) uniform vec2 u_mouse;
layout(location = 2) uniform mat4 M;
layout(location = 3) uniform mat4 V;
layout(location = 4) uniform mat4 P;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    vec4 vertex = a_points;
    gl_Position = P * V * M * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    color.x = vertex.a; // here i put the index of each point to reference the color
}
```

draw_points.frag

```
#version 450 core

in vec4 color;
out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    // Here i paint the points with its corresponding fragcoord and in the alpha i'm storing the index of each point
    FragColor = vec4(gl_FragCoord.xy, 0.0, color.x);
}
```

display_voronoi.vert

```
#version 450 core

out vec2 uv;

void main()
{
    vec2 v[4] = vec2[4]
    (
        vec2(-1.0, -1.0),
        vec2( 1.0, -1.0),
        vec2(-1.0,  1.0),
        vec2( 1.0,  1.0)
    );

    vec4 p = vec4(v[gl_VertexID], 0.9998, 1.0);
    gl_Position = p;
}
```

display_voronoi.frag

```
#version 450 core

layout(binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform image2D space; // here it's voronoi    
layout(binding = 2) uniform sampler1D colors; // color buffer


layout(location = 0) uniform int u_spaceSize;
layout(location = 1) uniform int points_size;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    float index = imageLoad(space, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy)).a; // here i get the index of each cell
    vec4 color = texelFetch(colors, int(index), 0); // using the index to get color     
FragColor = color; //vec4(index / (points_size - 1)); The commented part is my "debugger" if i use the index divided by the number of points, it paints in gray scale
}
```

Comment: Just a hunch - what if you change `int(index)` to `int(index + 0.5)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem happens because you are sampling the colors on screen space, using the fragments coords which will remain constant whatever zoom you perform (they will always be your window coordinates). So, when you perform zoom, you dont get actual zoomed, but you just reduce the range of indexes these fragment coordinates will sample. You should sample the colors in the first stage and store them in a g buffer as you do with the indexes.

Comment: but that doesn't explain the black and white voronoi (the last two images), as you can see i zoomed out and i didn't lose the indices. I generate 5 points with 5 colors so each point have an index in its alpha channel (0, 1, 2, 3 and 4) then i draw those points in a texture2D, but in the vertex shader of draw points first i pass the index in an out variable then i multiply my point like this gl_Position = P*V*M*vec4(point.xyz, 1.0) so basically im moving my points and thus the voronoi cells moves

Comment: @JacobCerón I thought the black and white images where debug images you generated to be sure they were the correct indexes as far as I understood from your post. You even say that it works like that.

Comment: i've solved my issue, the problem is the NVIDIA drivers. I'm in Linux Ubuntu 16 and i have the NVIDIA binary driver -version 384.130 from nvidia-324(proprietary, tested) and the X.Org X server -Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau(open source), and with the nouveau it works fine but if i change to the nvidia binary driver everything just goes bad. So i think the Nvidia binary drivers have some errors with opengl or the implementation is really different, thatś just my opinion. What do you think?

Comment: But i still need help please, what is the problem with nvidia drivers?

Comment: @Nadir Check out the *colours* in the first and second images, I gather that the images are meant to look the same.

Comment: the problem was the out vec4 color in the draw_points.vert shader and the in vec4 color in the fs, because the index should be int, i just changed to out int color, and to avoid the interpolation by the raster i add the qualifier flat in the input variable in the fragment shader. In the end i think is something with the floating point in how nvidia driver manage it. So thanks anyway and sorry.

Comment: @JacobCerón Im glad you resolved your issue. But if my answer wasnt the solution to your problem (as it appears), you shouldnt mark as correct. Post your own explaining the solution and mark ir as correct :)